# My app stops installing since i added play services library

Tags: android, google-play-services

My app was working great. I decided to add play services (just for location, cause this could provide a better experience for the user). So I added play services. (It took soooo much time to build :D). And after that, when I tried to install my app, it says that it can't be installed (nothing else, just written "the app could not be installed"). Do I have to upgrade play services to the last version ? Or what am I doing wrong ? (I will certainly answer tomorrow, not before. Sorry for the inconvenience)

EDIT:
Here's my `build.gradle` :app module file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "fr.zwedge.becomerich"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'
    compile 'com.rarepebble:colorpicker:1.7.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.pavelsikun:material-seekbar-preference:2.2.0'
    compile 'me.angrybyte.picker:picker:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.3.0'
//  compile 'com.github.jrvansuita:PickImage:2.1.2'
    compile 'com.github.nisrulz:screenshott:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.jraska:falcon:1.0.4'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:takt:1.0.4'
}
```

EDIT 2:
This is what appears everytime i try to install the app (translated: "Application not installed"
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

don't use compile `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'`

use `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'`

for location/replace your version like 10:0:1

Comment: I used "compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1' " and i changed from 9.2.1 to 10.2.1. Nothing changed... :( My app doesn't want to install... The only configuration I changed was adding compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.1' && play-services-location. And it stops installing :(

Comment: is there any message? let me see!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So i just started a new project, copied my `src` dir and my `build.gradle`...and it works. I don't know why. If someone has a response which can explain this problem, it may be great. But thanks for all ^^

---

EDIT: Got the solution ! My phone doesn't support Play Services (let me wonder why Play Store and other apps with PlayServicesBilling/Ads work on it :/)